# Converting an output (println!) to .csv file

Tags: web-scraping, rust, export-to-csv, yahoo-finance, writer

```
use yahoo_finance::{history, Interval, Timestamped};

#[tokio::main]

async fn main() {

    let data = history::retrieve_interval("AAPL", Interval::_6mo).await.unwrap();

    for end in &data {

        println!("Close ${:.2}, {}", end.close,end.datetime().format("%b %e %y)"));
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to take this program, and have the output as .csv file, not println!(), I just used println! to make sure the program worked. I'm still fairly new to Rust, and programming in general (apologies if I sound uneducated). I'm just making this program as something practical I can use (working in the finance industry) and build upon it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do exactly that by using the [`writeln!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.writeln.html) macro instead of `println!`. You will need something that implements the `Write` trait, for example a [`File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html). This needs to be passed as the first argument to `writeln!`.

Your example would then be written like this:

```
use yahoo_finance::{history, Interval, Timestamped};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let data = history::retrieve_interval("AAPL", Interval::_6mo).await.unwrap();

    // create a file called data.csv, overwriting the file if it already existed
    let mut file = std::fs::File::create("data.csv");

    for end in &data {
        // write to the file instead of standard output
        writeln!(file, "Close ${:.2}, {}", end.close,end.datetime().format("%b %e %y"));
    }
}
```

I removed the parenthesis in the date format, I think that was by mistake? Anyway I hope I could help.

As others have noted, this is not the cleanest solution possible and you might have to pay attention to quoting things yourself and such, so looking into using a CSV library might also be a good idea. But in this case I think it should work fine like this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`std::fs::File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) API which lets you create files. On these files, there is a [`write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.write) function into which you can pass in `String`. There is a `format!` macro that lets you do the same thing as `println!` but it returns a `String` instead. So if you piece this all together, you should be able to create a file with a name ending in `.csv` and then use the API to write stuff to it in a for loop like you did with `println!`.

Probably a more appropriate way to do this though is to look up a `csv` crate that can give you some more `csv` specific functionality. A quick search came up with [this library](https://docs.rs/csv/1.1.5/csv/).

Comment: There's also the [`writeln!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.writeln.html) macro which does the same thing as `println!` except it allows you to specify an output file instead of printing to the standard output.